# IE takes too much time to load the page compared to Firefox

Tags: performance, hibernate, internet-explorer, firefox, page-load-time

I have a page which displays around 1000 records.
The page gets loaded quite easily on firefox..around 2 seconds. But same on IE taking more that 10 seconds.

I checked performance tuning on server side, and modified the hibernate Criteria query returning this whole data. But issue is still there.

I also tried to remove almost all the plugins from IE thinking those could be the culprits. But no impact. :(

Trying to monitor the UI components on IE developer tool, but didnt find much details.

Any suggestions please. :)

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Which IE version, specifically?

Comment: IE 8. To be specific- IE 8.0.6001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys Got the Culprit here... :) :)

After doing lot of RnD on Server side and Client side, I took a look at "Developer Tool" in IE.
You can find something like "Document Mode: Quirks". If you check the Wiki page for this Quirks mode, You can find a definition as  "In computing, quirks mode refers to a technique used by some web browsers for the sake of maintaining backward compatibility with web pages designed for older browsers, instead of strictly complying with W3C and IETF standards in standards mode."

So this all becuase of checking for compatibility for all components on page. And hence the performance issue. :)

And When I changed this mode to IE 8 Standard. Things started working really well.

IE and its issues ...!!!! :D

Answer (score 3):

Performance issues like this will be down to rendering the UI. The server side processing won't vary from browser to browser, so it will be down to the way different browsers handle the drawing of the elements. Without seeing your page in action it is not easy to suggest anything to help improve your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I am trying to find a ways how this performance difference can be tracked..like impact of browser plugins, say caching..and many more. So trying to explore in all these.